# Unable to Start a Django Project

Tags: django, eclipse

I am new to Django. I am using Eclipse Juno for Django development on Windows 7.

I have installed Python2.7 correctly and created a project called Student in Eclipse. The project contains two subfolders: `src` and `python2.7`.

The `src` directory contains two files: `Student` and `init.py`. I am not able to create manage.py, settings.py etc. I used powershell to type `python manage.py startproject Student` inside `c:\Eclipse\workspace\Student` but I receive this error:

`can't open file 'manage.py':errno 2 No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination), `startproject` is to be executed like this:

```
python django-admin.py startproject Student
```

After you have completed that process, manage.py will be created for you.

Comment: It still says cant open file 'django-admin.py'

Comment: Check your installation. If Django is installed properly, django-admin.py will be in your path.

Comment: I have got it.when i delete the current project and recreated without adding anything in Django Settings page,every file automatically comes